# VBA - macro: dejar celdas vacias cuando hay un espacio

Tags: excel, vba, macros, data

tengo un codigo vba que lee los datos de un fichero dmp donde hay numeros de la siguiente forma:

```
5.32164 1.22355 2.56985 4.45215
5.30254 1.20545 2.54634 4.43155
5.28542         2.51366
                        4.38342
5.24153 1.13642
```

El problema son los espacios donde falta un dato (bien porque no se ha podido obtener). Al leer el fichero y colocarlo en excel, los numeros son colocados uno detras del otro sin tener en cuenta esa falta de datos, es decir se apilan todos al principio de la fila y luego si quiero hacer un grafica por ejmplo, muchos datos se encuentran en la posicion erronea. Quisiera saber como puedo hacer en el codigo visual basic de la macro para que cuando falte un dato, coloque una celda vacia en el excel. Muchas gracias

Edit: el programa actualmente al leer el fichero coloca los datos asi:

```
5.32164 1.22355 2.56985 4.45215
5.30254 1.20545 2.54634 4.43155
5.28542 2.51366
4.38342
5.24153 1.13642
```

Edit 2: añado el codigo que abre y copia el fichero a excel:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fichier_choisi, Local:=True _
    , Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
    Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
    Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15 _
    , 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        NomFicData & "temp_data.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    Cells.Select
    selection.Copy

    Workbooks(Fic).Worksheets(ShtTempo).Activate
    Sheets(ShtTempo).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Raul, por favor edita tu pregunta y añade tu código para que podamos ayudarte a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Ya esta añadido, perdona que se me paso justo eso

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Has probado a importarlo, pero en vez de como texto delimitado, eligiendo tú el ancho de los datos? Por lo que se ve en el ejemplo, todos tus datos tienen la misma cantidad de dígitos, así que podría funcionarte. Otra opción sería importarlos pero omitiendo la opción "Considerar delimitadores consecutivos como uno solo" a ver si así no te lo junta.

Comment: Hola, gracias! pues no he probado, soy muy nuevo con VBA y apenas se hacer cosas, ahi de momento lo estoy importando usando el espacio como unidad de separacion, pero como serian las dos opciones que dices exactamente?
Edit: el problema es que luego hay datos que no tienen el mismo numero de digitos tambien

Comment: Vale, si no tienen el mismo número de dígitos es diferente. Es que me basé en el ejemplo que pusiste. ¿Puedes subir un fichero de ejemplo para poder hacer pruebas? (Wetransfer, Google Drive o algo así) Sería más fácil ayudarte de esa manera.

Comment: Lo siento por la tardanza, he estado de viaje y no he podido responder antes. Pongo aqui un enlace a un archivo ejemplo: https://we.tl/t-dVdhf6LlCe. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, aun no consigo resolverlo